# Save on webpage with command line like in google chrome

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, wget

I need to grab one webpage (single page, not all site) with all his assets(images/css) in command line.

I really like how google chrome do it - if I save webpage I get single html file and single directory with all assets. Moreover all paths to images are changed to local ones, and all links are absolute (if it was "/pricing", it becomes "http://example.com/pricing").

I know I can do it with `wget`, but I don't like the result - many directories (if there was images from different domains), and html file is somewhere in directory (with domain name)..

I really like the result after saving page with google chrome and I need to know if you know some command line crawlers which makes similar result.

Or you know how to configure `wget` to do it like I need?

Comment: Can you post file listings of the folders created by Chrome and Wget and point out the differences you need? Also, look into `wget`'s `--convert-links` options, which converts "the links in the document to make them suitable for local viewing".

Comment: You may find the following bash script useful for what you need: https://github.com/abiyani/automate-save-page-as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions!

What I need was `--no-directories` parameter to `wget`. Then I get one directory with all files I need (html file, images, css files).

Sorry, the question wasn't well formulated.

Comment: Note that `--no-directories` should be used with `--recursive` or some other recursive downloading options.